# Recursion. Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, recursion

I am sure I am making a foolish mistake here but it beats me. Here is a piece of code:

```
void Main()
{
    //Key is a parent while the list contains its children
    Dictionary<string,List<string>> d = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
    d.Add("1",new List<string>(){"2","3"});//valid.should return false 
    d.Add("2",new List<string>(){"4"});//valid.should return false
    d.Add("3",new List<string>(){"5"});//valid.should return false
    d.Add("4",new List<string>(){"1"});//invalid.should return true 

   IsChildAlreadyAParent("4","2",d);
 }

private bool IsChildAlreadyAParent( string child, string parent, Dictionary<string, List<string>> d )
{           
    if( !d.ContainsKey( child ) || ( d.ContainsKey( child ) && d[child].Count == 0 ))
    {
        return false;
    }

    foreach( string childOfChild in d[child] )
     {
        if( childOfChild == parent )
            return true;

        if( IsChildAlreadyAParent( childOfChild, parent, d ) ) return true;
    }
}
```

Compiling this gives me this error:

> `IsChildAlreadyAParent(string, string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>)'`: not all code paths return a value

I have read the code a few times and I cant see how a return condition would be missed. I know I can rectify it by adding a method return statement before the method end but it doesn't help me understand the issue at hand. Where is the gap??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might think this executes the loop body exactly once, always returning from the function:

> ```
> foreach( string childOfChild in d[child] )
> {
>     if( childOfChild == parent )
>         return true;
>
>     return IsChildAlreadyAParent( childOfChild, parent, d );
> }
> ```

But what if `d[child]` has no elements at all?

Also, testing only the first child probably isn't the right solution either.

Better:

```
foreach( string childOfChild in d[child] )
{
    if( childOfChild == parent ) return true;
    if (IsChildAlreadyAParent( childOfChild, parent, d )) return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: modified the code to handle that as well...still the same issue and i dont wan't to use a method return at the end as u have done here..

Comment: but the point that is raised, "testing only the first child probably isn't the right solution either", was helpful

Comment: @wanderer: Sorry, the compiler isn't smart enough to notice that you've already tested for an empty list.  So it still is concerned with what happens below the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is complaining because in the case where the `d[child]` collection is empty the loop body will never run.  There is no `return` on that particular code path and hence you get an error.

Additionally your version of the code will lookup `child` in the dictionary 3 times on a successful execution.  You could optimize this to only do one lookup with `TryGetValue`.

Here's the code with a couple of fixes

```
private bool IsChildAlreadyAParent(
  string child, 
  string parent, 
  Dictionary<string, List<string>> d )
{           
    List<string> list;
    if (!d.TryGetValue(child, out list) || list.Count == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (list[0] == parent)
    {
      return true;
    }

    return IsChildAlreadyAParent(list[0], parent, d );
}
```

Comment: @wanderer my bad, fixed the typo.  Should compile now

Comment: @wanderer yes, but that's how your original sample functioned.  The loop only ever did a single iteration.  It either matched `parent` or it immediately called into `IsChildAlreadyAParent` with effectively `list[0]`.

Comment: @jaredpar....my fault..sorry. was a mistake...i wanted to iterate the complete list checking for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

What if `d[child]` has a length of 0? So your for-loop won't run -> no return value

Answer (score 0):

It might happen that your code never gets into "foreach"...you should have return at the end...if d[child] doesn't have elements at all...

Answer (score 0):

well, what if your list is empty?

Not to mention the foreach loop is pointless.  It will always terminate on the first iteration.